# How do I reduce the response body size of a SP.CamlQuery to a large SharePoint list?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, caml

I have been having trouble constructing an efficient caml query to a sharepoint list. It is a very large list with many columns. I have used 'ViewFields' to reduce the columns returned to only the three that we need. In doing so, this reduced the returned file from 8mb to 4mb, which was great. I would like to further reduce this if it is possible. I noticed that there is a section in the response body that is labeled 'meta-info' - it is quite large and doesn't seem to contain info that is needed, is there anyway to construct the caml query to omit this info, or to otherwise further reduce the size of the response?
Here is my code:

```
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/path/to/list');
oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List Name');

camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\'Col1\'/><FieldRef Name=\'Col2\'/><FieldRef Name=\'Col3\'/></ViewFields></View>');

this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem); 
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could page the requests to reduce the negative effect of bringing that much data across the wire.

[SP.ListItemCollectionPosition Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409439.aspx)